# Professional Systems Engineering Consultant

Tags: systems-engineering

I know that specific engineering disciplines (electrical, mechanical etc) require a PE license to consult. Does the same apply to systems engineering?

Comment: Actually... the need of a US state issued PE will depend on what you are doing.  There are some things that require a sign off or stamp from such who becomes responsible for the design.  On top of it all there are also some things that you can't do even if you have such- for example you may need a PE from a specific state or a different form of credential altogether.  You should look into the laws for what you intend to do; you probably don't need a PE to consult on design of paperclips...

Comment: Although Stack Exchange is based in the US, you need to specify your location for any question that depends on local regulations. For example, in most Canadian provinces it is usually (with a few exceptions) illegal to describe what you doing professionally as "engineering" if you are not a Professional Engineer. For example, you cannot call yourself a "[software engineer](https://engineerscanada.ca/news-and-events/news/engineering-regulators-reiterate-licensure-requirements-for-those-using-software-engineer-and-other-it-titles)" unless you are a P.Eng.

Answer (score 1):

This will be regulated by the state you are in.  My reading of the Louisiana document "[INFORMATION ON ARCHITECTURE AND ENGINEERING LICENSURE LAWS AND RULES IN LOUISIANA](https://www.lapels.com/docs/Laws_and_Rules/Architect_and_Engineering_Licensure_Laws_and_Rules_July_2012.pdf)" leads me to say that if you are offering yourself an an engineering consultant, licensure would be required.  My reading is if you would call it engineering, so would the state.  My guess is also that you would struggle to obtain professional liability insurance without a license.

> "Engineer" or "professional engineer" shall mean an individual who, by
> reason of his special knowledge and ability to apply the mathematical,
> physical, and engineering sciences and the principles and methods of
> engineering analysis and design, acquired by an engineering education
> and engineering experience, is qualified to practice engineering, as
> evidenced by his licensure as such by the board.
>
> "Practice of engineering" shall mean responsible professional service
> which may include consultation, investigation, evaluation, planning,
> designing, or inspection of construction in connection with any public
> or private utilities, structures, machines, equipment, processes,
> works, or projects wherein the public welfare or the safeguarding of
> life, health, and property is concerned or involved, when such
> professional service requires the application of engineering
> principles and the interpretation of engineering data.       (b) A
> person shall be construed to practice or offer to practice
> engineering: who practices in any discipline of the profession of
> engineering; or who, by verbal claim, sign, advertisement, letterhead,
> card, or in any other way represents himself to be a professional
> engineer; or who represents himself as able to perform; or who does
> perform any engineering service or work or any other professional
> service designated by the practitioner or recognized by educational
> authorities as engineering. The practice of engineering shall not
> include the work ordinarily performed by a person who himself
> operates or maintains machinery or equipment.
>
> "Responsible professional services" shall mean the technical
> responsibility, control, and direction of the investigation, design,
> or construction of engineering service or work requiring initiative,
> engineering ability, and its use of independent judgment.

The [Industrial Engineering exam](https://ncees.org/exams/pe-exam/industrial-and-systems/) includes a section on Systems Engineering.

Note that I am **not** a licensed Professional Engineer.  I consider being an engineer a state of mind.  But the State considers that if you sell yourself as an engineer, you generally need to be licensed.